# Xrandr not doing anything on Lenovo laptop

Tags: display, lenovo, xrandr

I am running Ubuntu 21.10 on a Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 15ARH05, and xrandr does not work. For example xrandr -o left does not do anything. Rotating screen through the GUI settings does work. Is there a way to find out whether xrandr supports my hardware, and if not, how can I rotate my screen through the terminal? (I want a script to be able to do this.)

Output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```

Comment: If you just type in `xrandr` what is the output (please copy the text output and paste it into your question, do not add a screenshot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running Ubuntu 21.10, you are on a Wayland session by default, after a fresh install and even after an upgrade. `xrandr` only works on the classical Xorg display driver.

You can still switch to Xorg. Log out, then on the log in screen, before entering your password, select the cog icon and select "Ubuntu on Xorg" to run the Ubuntu desktop in Xorg.